# A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am getting below error while starting tomcat. My application is using Spring security 4.0.2 and Spring 4.2.1

With single spring security file i.e application-security.xml It is working perfectly but when I introduced a new jar which exposed spring-rest feature in same web application then I am getting this error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration

I have read may suggestion on stackoverflow.com and other tutorial but could not find the right one to solve my issue.

Here is my application configuration

**web.xml**

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationLmc.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>lmc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lmc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**application-security.xml**

```
<http security="none" pattern="/resources/**" />
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/termsandservice" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/contact" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/faq" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/jobs" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/terms" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/privacy" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/blog" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/signupvalidation" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll" method="POST"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/forgotPasswordPage" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/generatePasswd" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/resetPassword" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/passwordReset" access="permitAll" method="POST"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"></intercept-url>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="lmcAuthSuccessHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" expired-url="/login" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="lmcAuthManager" />
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="lmcAuthManager" class="com.lmc.web.security.auth.LMCAuthManager" />
<beans:bean id="lmcAuthSuccessHandler" class="com.lmc.web.security.auth.LMCAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

As per multiple suggestion over web, I found that I should defined pattern value in application-security file. But I am not sure what pattern value I need to put because all these needs to be access from web root.

Following is applicationRestService.xml is REST configuration with spring security details

**applicationRestService.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.lmc.rest" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <security:http pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
                <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
                <security:logout />
            </security:http>
            <security:authentication-manager alias="lmcRestAuthManger">
                <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
            </security:authentication-manager>
            <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.lmc.rest.security.RestAuthenticationUserDetailService" />
            <bean class="com.lmc.rest.security.RestStatelessAuthenticationFilter" id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
                    <value>/api/**</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="lmcRestAuthManger"></property>
            </bean>
            <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.lmc.rest.security.LMCRestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    </beans>
```

Thanks reading it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Switch the order. Load `applicationRestService` before `application-security.xml`.

Comment: I changed order of applicationRestService  in my main applicationLmc.xml
by flipping <import resource>.  Seems its working. Now, I have to invoke my REST service to see authentication is working or not.